# Identical Geodesics implies scalar multiple of metric?

Tags: geometry, metric-spaces, arc-length, metric-geometry

Suppose $(M,g^1)$ and $(M,g^2)$ are two intrinsic metric spaces with the same underlying set $M$.

Assume that for every $p,q\in M$, for each geodesic $\gamma^1_{[p,q]}$ connecting $p$ to $q$ under $g^1$ there exist a geodesic and $\gamma^2_{[p,q]}$ connecting p and q and $g^2$ identical to it, and visa-versa.

Does this imply that $g^1$ is a multiple of $g^2$?

Comment: In your second sentence, what is meant by "the" geodesics....connecting $p$ to $q$.  What if there is more than one?

Comment: Good point, I modified the statement to account for this.

Comment: Are you really talking about metric sapces, or did you mean to say "Riemannian manifolds"? I ask because $(M,g)$ is the usual notation for Riemannian manifolds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Consider as your model set $M$ a tripod. (A tripod is a graph with one vertex of degree three and three vertices of degree one attached to it.)

For your different length metrics, just assign the edges of the tripods various different lengths, and equip the space with the length metric induced by those edge lengths (making each edge into an isometric copy of $[0,L]$ where $L$ is its length.)

Any two such tripods have the same setwise geodesics, but need not have the same metrics, even up to scaling.

Comment: You answer looks nice, just be sure that you use the proper terminology. i havent learnt this subject so I have no idea if you are. I just noticed that you seemed to treat tripod as a made up term. I am just here becuase of some "first answer by person" review thing I was told to take care of. Anyway, welcome to MSE!

Comment: TheGreatDuck: In mathematics many people use different terminology for the same objects and the same terminology for different objects. You may find in life that it is worth a sentence to explain your notation, even if you believe it to be "standard". That is what I did.

Comment: no need to explain yourself. I just tell that to everyone with the potential of that issue. :p

Comment: Great answer, Thanks Anon and Welcome to MSE ! :)

Answer (score 4):

Your notation suggested another alternative:  Let $g^2 = (g^1)^2$ -- a local extremum of $g^1$ is also a local extremum of its square.  In fact, let $\phi$ be strictly increasing on $[ 0, \infty )$, then $g^2 = \phi(g^1)$ replicates the extrema of $g^1$.  So geodesics (paths whose length is first order stationary under perturbation, hence correspond to local extrema) are preserved under any such $\phi$.

Comment: I was leaning towards the same sort of idea, thanks for making it concrete Eric :)

Answer (score 1):

While Anon's answer is correct, here is an example from Riemannian geometry. Start with $(M,g)$ equal to the projective plane with the standard metric of constant curvature, so that geodesics are projective lines. Let $f: M\to M$ be a generic projective transformation and $g'=f^*(g)$ be the pull-back of $g$. Then the two Riemannian manifolds $(M,g), (M,g')$ have exactly the same set of geodesics but are not even conformal to each other.